# how to implement multi imageView select holding control button in javaFX

Tags: java, imageview, javafx-2, multi-select, javafx-css

In my JAVAFX application, i am having imageviews in a tilepane , i want to implement the multi select like functionality like in android for images . I tried adding border style to the imageView on click event but that didnt work. Is there any way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You can embed the `Image` in a JavaFX `Button`, and set the `OnAction` methods of the `Button`:

```
imageButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Changing the color of the button's border :");
        imageButton.setStyle("-fx-border-color:blue;");
        System.out.println("For further reference, you can save the button or the image in a TreeSet:");
        treeSet.add(imageButton);
    }
});
```

If a simple click is enough to select the image, you can define the OnAction method of the Button like above. However if you need a long click (push and hold in Android style) to change the selection status of the image, you can find more information on 'push and hold' click here : [how to achieve javafx mouse event "push and hold"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25601266/how-to-achieve-javafx-mouse-event-push-and-hold) .

Comment: Pleasure, do not hesitate to validate the answer !