# Copy and paste in JavaFX TextField when running in Android

Tags: android, javafx, javafxports

JavaFX TextField controls when running in Android have handlers to make it easier to select portions of the text. But there is not built-in support for actions like copy, cut and paste, when doing a long tap on selected text it does not appear any contextual menu.

Support for these actions can be activated using any property or has to be developed from scratch?

Comment: See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40561927/textfield-copy-action-on-long-hold-copy-popup/40564213#40564213).