# How to detect occurence of ContextMenu in OS?

Tags: android, ios, javafx, gluon

Im using Gluon to develop javafx applications to Android, Iphone (and to desktop). When I export a test application to my Android phone (Marshmallow 6.0) - *I cannot hold down onto text to access the menu from where you can copy text (the context menu)*
**(Which is an example of what you can do with a context menu - and is not a question of how to copy text on long hold specifically in Android)**.

This was possible on iphone 6 when testing it there.

**How can I detected wether the device/operating system has a default context menu or not in java?**

Comment: See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40561927/textfield-copy-action-on-long-hold-copy-popup/40564213#40564213) about getting the device's `ContextMenu`, and also enabling the long press.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Textfield copy action on long hold (copy popup)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40561927/textfield-copy-action-on-long-hold-copy-popup)

Comment: Thank you José. Stephen just... read the title or something I don´t know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Desktop there is a default `ContextMenu` that is created and installed in `TextFieldBehavior` (private API). If you don't set your own custom context menu, that will be the one used when a `ContextMenuEvent` is fired (with a right click event for instance).

On mobile, both Android and iOS **have** a `ContextMenu` as well.

On iOS, it uses a native `TextField` (`UITextField`). When the long press event happens, it triggers the default context menu (on my iPad I can see a small magnifying glass, and after that the context menu shows up).

On Android, the JavaFX `TextField` has a custom skin, but shares the same private `TextFieldBehavior` as the desktop version. The problem in this case is the missing right click event that would trigger the `ContextMenuEvent` event.

That's why you have to fire manually a `ContextMenuEvent` event, as it was described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40561927/textfield-copy-action-on-long-hold-copy-popup/40564213#40564213).

Conclusion: so far, this is basically required only on Android:

```
TextField textField = new TextField();

addPressAndHoldHandler(textField, Duration.seconds(1), event -> {
        Bounds bounds = textField.localToScreen(textField.getBoundsInLocal());
        textField.fireEvent(new ContextMenuEvent(ContextMenuEvent.CONTEXT_MENU_REQUESTED, 
                0, 0, bounds.getMinX() + 10, bounds.getMaxY() + 10, false, null));
    });
```