# JavaFX Long pressButton

Tags: javafx, gluon-mobile

I'm currently building a Mobile app in JavaFx with the GluonMobile plugins and I try to find a way to know if the user just tap the button or if the button is pressed for over 2 second.

I try a couple of thing and I run into some problem.

The thing is I found this method on the web and he's my problem

First the code

```
button.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.ANY, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        long startTime;

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            if (event.getEventType().equals(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED)) {
                startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            } else if (event.getEventType().equals(MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED)) {
                if (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime > 2 * 1000) {
                    System.out.println("Pressed for at least 2 seconds (" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) + " milliseconds)");
                } else
                    System.out.println("Pressed for " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) + " milliseconds");
            }
        }
    });
```

The problem that I have here is really weird.

When I click the button the method work. 
If I click for over 2 sec it will printLn the good result.

BUT

If I click a second time on it it will print the PrintLn 2 times.
If I click a 3rd time, it will print the result 3 time...

So the problem is when I put a method (let's say a dialogBox) the box will show 3 times.

It's like if the program had a memory of how many time I click it and give me the result the number of time I click the button.

Can I "reset" the memory of the method?

Thanks.

Jc

EDIT

```
   @FXML
   public void buttonClick(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

        btn1.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.ANY, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            long startTime;

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                if (event.getEventType().equals(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED)) {
                    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                } else if (event.getEventType().equals(MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED)) {
                    if (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime > 2 * 1000) {
                        System.out.println("Pressed for at least 2 seconds (" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) + " milliseconds)");
                    } else
                        System.out.println("Pressed for " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) + " milliseconds");
                }
            }
        });


    }
```

Comment: There is a "long press event" snippet here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41526346/3956070

Comment: Regarding your issue, it works fine for me, but it looks like you are adding the event filter to the button over and over again? Can you post your view?

Comment: I edit the first post

Comment: Hmm..., every time you click the button, you are adding a _new_ event filter.

Comment: true. Forgot the event.consume();
Work fine now. Thanks.

But I love your longpress!!

Comment: Even if you consume the event, it is better to set the event filter just once, i.e. in the `initialize()` method.